# Insert footer in PowerPoint Web Add-in

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins

I know that Word Web Add-In supports editing of footers and headers. But I'm unable to do so in PowerPoint.

Is it possible to insert and edit footer in PowerPoint document via Web Add-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible today. please use our uservoice channel to request this feature.
thanks!

Comment: To elaborate on Juan's response, "UserVoice" is the Microsoft forum where customers can submit (and vote on) feature requests. You can find the Office Developer Platform UserVoice page here:  https://officespdev.uservoice.com/.

Comment: Is it possible to use OOXML SDK service as you suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466762/powerpoint-web-add-in-get-data-within-document/45467060#45467060 to edit footers and headers?

Comment: updating content is different. you can certainly create a new PPT with header/footer or whatever you want but that will be a new file, will not affect the file where the add-in is activated.