# PowerPoint Web Add-In: get data within document

Tags: office-js, office-addins

Is it possible to get all data in PPT document?

Something like [getSelectedDataAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getselecteddataasync) method but for all data whether selected or not.

I want to verify the content(Text) of the PPT document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PPT JS API is not yet as rich as the Excel and Word ones, and today there is no API to do this directly. There is an intricate workaround where you need to get the entire file (pptx) (using [the getFileAsync method](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfileasync)) send it to  service that uses [the OOXML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) to open it and grab the content you need.

Comment: To elaborate on Juan's response -- feel free to log this as a feature request in "UserVoice" (the Microsoft forum where customers can submit (and vote on) feature requests). You can find the Office Developer Platform UserVoice page here:  https://officespdev.uservoice.com/.

Comment: Finally there's something I can do with this API